# Can't install perl with perlbrew

Tags: perlbrew

I encountered the error when install perl-5.14.2 with perlbrew.

On Ubuntu11.10(64-bit), I try

```
$ perlbrew install perl-5.14.2 -Dperlibs='-lm -lc' -Dusethreads -Dplibpth=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

and got the error

```
IO.xs: In function ‘XS_IO__Poll__poll’:
IO.xs:249:17: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct pollfd’
```

How can i solve this error?

Comment: I had the same errors, but for me the issues was actually a bad include path. [This answer](http://serverfault.com/a/293231/370662) solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change `#  include <poll.h>` to `#  include <sys/poll.h>` in `<perlDownloadDir>/dist/IO/poll.h`

Detail solution is in [Make error when compiling Perl 5.12.1 (RHEL 5.5)](https://serverfault.com/questions/145288/make-error-when-compiling-perl-5-12-1-rhel-5-5)

Comment: ```#include <poll.h>``` -> ```#include <sys/poll.h>```